# Summing long numbers as learning exercise

Tags: c#, math, numbers

I am trying to make a class for arbitrary size numbers. I want to redefine all operations in my class. How can I create a `sum(params string[] numbers);` function to sum the numbers?

Or could you provide me sites or tutorials about this topic?

**I want my class to make operations with numbers like ones with 50-100 digits for example (in fact, very very large numbers)**

I thought about a function to sum every char and return the sum as a `string`, but I don't know how to implement it...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is wrong with `BigInteger`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Do you just want to sum to the numbers passed in?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean 'arbitrary' size, not infinite size. Unless your computer has infinite memory, you can't store infinite size numbers.

Comment: I want my class to make operations with numbers like ones with 150-200 digits for example (in fact, very very large numbers)

Comment: @DanielA.White, gave you that BigInteger. There's a constructor overload that will take Byte[]

Answer (score 5):

What about the [`BigInteger` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Comment: +1. BigInteger is good to use and learn (at least look at interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

Use something already tested like IntX

http://intx.codeplex.com/

You are welcome!

Comment: Thank you for this library. I have already known about it, and I used it in the past. But I want to create this class just for learning more...

Comment: Then I recommend you to do some TDD (good excersice) and take advantage of method overloading in your class. have fun!